Why are the underlines removed from my hyperlinks and no numbers on ordered list?
Below is my backend code that send HTML to my frontend react app and I am using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render this data. For some reason (don't know if this is the right behavior) my hyperlinks don't have underlines and my ordered lists dont have numbers:
const html = `<div>bro what <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a><ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol> </div>`

const summary = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;


Am I missing something?

CSS Reset or Default Styling: Your React app might have a CSS reset or default styling that removes underlines from hyperlinks and styling from ordered lists. Check your CSS files or the CSS applied by your React framework to see if any rules affect these elements.
Global CSS Styles: There could be global CSS styles applied to  tags and 

Take a look at the Elements -> Styles section (Chrome) or Inspector (FF) in the development tools of your browser (F12) to find out which styles are applied to the respective elements. Mabe this will help you find the overriding CSS.

Yea found out that some css is getting inherited from other components. Thank you for the help
